# Powershell variable contains the value twice

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that is started bij a jenskinsfile. This all works well. But in the script I have a function to download a file. This does not work, because the `$filePath` variable contains the value twice. When this part would be run the log would look like:

```
https://example.com/api/download
D:\folder\file_2.txt D:\folder\file_2.txt
```

How can I get the value only to be there ones in `$filePath` ?

```
function DownloadFile ($folder, $version) {

    $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $wc.Headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

    $requesturl = "https://example.com/api/download"
    $filePath = Join-Path -Path $folder -ChildPath "\file_$version.txt"

    Write-Host "$requesturl"
    Write-Host "$filePath"

    $wc.DownloadFile($requesturl, $filePath)

    return $filePath
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication is that the argument you're passing to the `-folder` parameter (as represented inside your function as the `$folder` parameter variable) is an *array* of folder paths, not a single one.

The solution is therefore to make sure that you only pass a *single* folder path when you call your `DownloadFile` function; e.g.:

```
DownloadFile -folder D:\folder -version 2

# With *positional* parameter binding:
DownloadFile D:\folder 2
```

---

Since [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) accepts an *array* of paths as a `-Path` argument, it outputs *multiple* paths when given an array; e.g.:

```
PS> $folder = 'c:\abc', 'c:\def'; Join-Path -Path $folder -ChildPath file.txt
c:\abc\file.txt
c:\def\file.txt
```

Passing an array [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) implicitly *stringifies* it, which means creating a single string composed of the array elements joined with spaces:

```
PS> $folder = 'c:\abc', 'c:\def'; Write-Host $folder
c:\abc c:\def
```

(Note that this differs from implicit output / output via [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), which prints each array element on its own line; also, implicit output / `Write-Output` write to the *pipeline*, meaning they output *data* for later processing, whereas `Write-Host` writes *strings to the display*).